# Is it possible to create a circular blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

This question may sound stupid, it just came to my mind and couldn't find much related info on Google.

Let's say there are 3 blocks of data: A, B and C

Normally blockchain is for chronological order: B contains the hash of A and C contains the hash of B.

But is it possible to create a block chain that A contains the hash of C to form a circular block chain?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you have to spend a very, very long time trying to find the contents of block C to match the hash in block A.